# Beginning in Lua for Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have started working on Corona SDK.As you all know it uses Lua as the programming language,i wanted to know some good links or ebooks which i can refer to begin development.I am an iPhone developer and working on objective C since last 1 year.

Any suggestions,help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Aditya

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been using this: [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/), first edition (FREE online edition of the book)
The [Corona SDK forums](https://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/7) are also good for specific issues related to the SDk itself. It seems it is having a few database problems just right now, but you might want to check it later.

Edit: just for completeness, here is the link to the [Lua Bookstore](http://astore.amazon.com/lua-store-20) @ amazon (not an affiliate link).

Comment: Note that PiL is for 5.0 and Corona uses 5.1. So be careful. :-)

Comment: I have to correct myself: FREE edition of PiL is for 5.0. Non-free PiL II is for 5.1

Comment: Hey @Rodrigo Thanks i had been to the site of Lua but didn't give a close look so couldn't find any eBooks...

Comment: The current (5.2, non-free) version of PiL is much better: much more explanation of why the language is the way it is.

Comment: The lua bookstore @ Amazon (not an affiliate link): http://astore.amazon.com/lua-store-20

Answer (score 11):

You can also check out http://learningcorona.com/ which has a huge listing of tutorials for Corona.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a great resource for learning Lua, it's aimed towards beginner programmers (doesn't sound like you), but it does a great job at introducing Lua and most of the basic concepts:

Lua for Beginners:

http://lua.gts-stolberg.de/en/index.php?uml=1

That, as well as the "Learning Corona" section of the Ansca docs should be plenty enough to get you up to speed in a *very* short amount of time:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/resources/docs/

TIP: Start working on a project, or converting an existing app using Corona and you'll learn it blazing fast! That's what I did, and I learned it quickly enough to have one of my games fully converted in about 8 days.

Answer (score 3):

For understanding basics of CORONA SDK I will prefer **"Corona.SDK.Mobile.Game.Development.Beginners.Guide"** 
book from Packtpub publication.
and You can also check out http://www.learningcorona.com/ for tutorial both video and audio.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lua Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1) is also an excellent read: Concise and complete.

[Lua Gems](http://www.lua.org/gems) is also worth looking at (at least the freely available snippets).

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Beginning Lua Programming](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Lua-Programming.productCd-0470069171.html) book to be pretty good as a complete reference for Lua with good example code.

Answer (score 2):

My very personal advice is just take a look at great books (Programming in LUA is covering everything) and switch as soon as possibles to samples / tutorials in order to learn all the API functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Corona sdk video tutorials on YouTube. One demonstrates how to create a simple balloon game in a few minutes. You can have Your Lua editor in one window and YouTube in another, and click on the video to start/stop and switch to the editor and type in the code. Some tutorials provide  links to download the code.

Answer (score 1):

hello  you can use their website they have good documentation you will find it here

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/